# What do I return for binary search of objects?

Tags: java

```
public Song searchSongByName (String name) {
  // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
  int low = 0;
  int high = items.length - 1;
  String foundName = "";
  while ( low <= high ) {
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    if ( items[mid].getName().compareTo(name) == 0) {
      foundName+= name;;
    } else {

      if ( items[mid].getName().compareTo(name) == -1 ) {
        low = mid;
      } else {
        high = mid;
      }
    }
  }
```

}

This is for a project I'm working on, basically, "items" is an object array of songs and I need to search the array looking for the song given in the parameter. My first idea was to return just the string i made "`foundName`" but that didn't work out. Then I thought of return -1 (if not found) and 0 (if found) but the return type is Song. So what can I return to let the user know that their song was found?

Comment: You stated that `items` is an array of Song, and that the method needs to return a Song object, so why not simply return `items[mid]` object if its name matches the name String? This would make the most sense to me.

Comment: Also, why not simply iterate through the array using a for loop? or using a Stream?

Comment: what can I return if their song is never found?

Comment: @GGar That would be upto the contract of the method- return `null` is one option, raising an exception is another, returning a dummy object a third.

Comment: Either return `null` or throw an exception such as an `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Since it looks like this is for a school project, I assume returning `null` will be sufficient unless the project is specifically about exception handling. If this was code in the wild, I'd say to deprecate this function and make a new one that returns an optional value.

Answer (score 3):

I think that items is something like that

```
Song[] items = ...
```

So you should return this if found

```
// instead of line // foundName+= name;;
return items[mid];
```

And return `null` after the while loop, if not found.

But if you can change the return type of your method you should rather return an `Optional`:

```
// instead of line // foundName+= name;;
return Optional.of(items[mid]);
```

In this case return `Optional.empty()`, if not found.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use Java 8 streams, to wit:

```
// written to return null if song name not found
public static Song searchSong(String name) {        
    return Arrays.stream(items)
            .filter(e -> e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
}
```

improved as per Makoto's comment

---

code breakdown:

```
// convert items array into a Stream using java.util.Arrays
Arrays.stream(items)

    // filter the Stream to get only Songs whose name match the name String (ignoring case)
    .filter(e -> e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))

    // find the first item in the filtered Stream
    .findFirst()

    // return this item or null, if nothing found
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: You *could* shorten this to `return optionalSong.orElse(null)` to make this more concise.  Returning the optional would be the most ideal but this is an okay compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search returns the index where the element is found in an array of objects. It does not return the element itself.

Hence, the return type of binary search method should be `int`.

To get the object itself later, as an example you can do:

```
int index = binarySearch("Never Gonna Give You Up");
if (index > -1)
  Song rickAstleySong = items[index];
```